# Getting MessageEdited for last 100 message for each chat

Tags: telegram, telethon

I have registered MessageEdited event in my telethon, but I have got only a few of them. I think there is a limit on the count of last messages of each chat, that telegram sends updates for them. If yes, how many is that?

And also how can I receive updates for last 100 messages per chat, in telethon?

Comment: The library currently does not fetch updates manually, so you only receive those that Telegram decides to send to you.

Comment: @Lonami Is there any rule about how many last message updates telegram usually sends? 
And is there any way to register for a special message update?